# Unable to Parse json.Showing deprecated api warning

Tags: json, scala

```
scala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull(value)
```

This is deprecated in scala and is giving me warning.I searched a lot and not sure what to use.What do i use in place of this??Im a newbie to scala please help

Comment: There are many dedicated libraries, [Play Json](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJson) is beginner friendly. you can also take a look at circe, spray json, ...